# How to center a label's text in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, label

I have a cell with two labels. How can I programmatically center-align the top label and hide the second label?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel Align Text to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722730/uilabel-align-text-to-center)

Answer (score 8):

`UITextAlignmentCenter` is deprecated. You should use the following:

```
labelOne.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 4):

[labelOne setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter]; //to center text in the UILabel
    [labelTwo setHidden:YES] //there, but not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is:
Something like this..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    firstLabel.frame = cell.frame; // or reconfigure your frame or some reason(i dont know)
    firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    secondLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

you want you text from the firstLabel to be at the center of the cell?