# UILabel Align Text to center

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text, alignment, uilabel

How do I align text in `UILabel`?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

From **iOS 6** and later `UITextAlignment` is deprecated. use `NSTextAlignment`

```
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

**Swift Version from iOS 6 and later**

```
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: swift version could be simplified :) myLabel.textAlignment = .Center

Comment: .center ← lowercase

Answer (score 83):

Here is a sample code showing how to align text using UILabel:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 30, 200, 12)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

You can read more about it here [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Comment: `UITextAlignment` is deprecated since iOS 5. Use `NSTextAlignment` instead.

Comment: False, UITextAligment is deprecated. In UIStringDrawing.h (UIKit) you can find this code: `// Deprecated: use NSTextAlignment enum in UIKit/NSText.h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITextAlignment) {
    UITextAlignmentLeft = 0,
    UITextAlignmentCenter,
    UITextAlignmentRight,                   // could add justified in future
} NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0,6_0);
`

Answer (score 13):

To center text in a UILabel in Swift (which is targeted for iOS 7+) you can do:

```
myUILabel.textAlignment = .Center
```

Or

```
myUILabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Answer (score 8):

**N.B.: As per the [UILabel class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html), as of iOS 6 this approach is now deprecated.**

Simply use the `textAlignment` property to see the required alignment using one of the `UITextAlignment` values. (`UITextAlignmentLeft`, `UITextAlignmentCenter` or `UITextAlignmentRight`.)

e.g.: `[myUILabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];`

See the [UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Use `yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;` for iOS >= 6.0 and `yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` for iOS < 6.0.

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 3 it's:

```
label.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 4):

IO6.1 
`[lblTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];`

Answer (score 3):

```
Label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 3):

In xamarin ios
suppose your label name is title then do the following

```
title.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: The question is not about Xamarin. And `UITextAlignment` is [deprecated in iOS 6](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextalignment?language=objc)!

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2** and Xcode 10

```
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 230, height: 21))
lbl.textAlignment = .center //For center alignment
lbl.text = "This is my label fdsjhfg sjdg dfgdfgdfjgdjfhg jdfjgdfgdf end..."
lbl.textColor = .white
lbl.backgroundColor = .lightGray//If required
lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)

 //To display multiple lines in label
lbl.numberOfLines = 0
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

lbl.sizeToFit()//If required
yourView.addSubview(lbl)
```